# How to call cache method on Observables in rxjs

Tags: rxjs5

I'm new to rxjs.
I wanted to know whether below code is correct or any correction needed?

```
var rxjs_1 = require('rxjs');    
rxjs_1.Observable.defer(function() {

            })

            .cache(1);
```

By above code I'm facing issue with cache (it is throwing the error : rxjs_1.Observable.defer(...).cache is not a function).

I checked in node_modules for the installed rxjs and in Observable.js file there is no method called cache.

could you please tell me how to call cache on Observable in rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called cache in the observable.js file since they add it to the prototype. Check rxjs/add/operator/cache.js for the javascript file.

If I look at the documentation of defer (here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/defer.md), I see you are supposed to return an observable from the defer function. You are not doing this in your code example. This is probably why you get the error that the function does not exists.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to cache the content before returning the Observable.
Location given above rxjs/add/operator/cache.js does not contain a cache.js file in rxjs(version 5.x) library.

Comment: It appears cache was removed starting from version 5.0.0RC1: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/commit/1b23ace That's probably why you are getting the error.